# How to gracefully shutting down the embedded jetty server application?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jetty, spring-boot

I had setup my springboot project by using jetty embedded server inside a war file. So basically, my war file is an executable file.

I setup main class that implements ServletContextInitializer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class CrawlerApplication implements ServletContextInitializer {


  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CrawlerApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.setInitParameter("mainComponentClass", "com.datalyst.crawler.component.CrawlerServiceTopComponent");
  }
}
```

And then I also have Configuration java file

```
@Configuration
public class CrawlerConfig {

  @Bean
  public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory(){
    return new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(8080);
  }

}
```

This is the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
     baseName = 'crawler-service'
     version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
configurations {
  providedRuntime
}

bootRepackage{
  enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    compile spec.external.springBootStarterWeb
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.6.RELEASE'

    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
}
```

Now, I managed to build it and start the server by executing this command:
`nohup java -jar crawler-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war > crawler-service.log &`.

I am using nohup to run it as a background service.

Now when I want to stop that program, I have to manually investigate the correspondence PID of `ps aux | grep java` and shutting down gracefully by executing `sudo kill PID`. But I want it to be better.

Is there any way to gracefully shutting down the service? Like for example by assigning STOP_PORT to that service when starting it, and then stop it by using that STOP_PORT?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method I use to shutdown Jetty 9. It is called via a button on my Jsf application:

```
public void shutdown() {
    log.info("Stopping server ...");
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // workaround (maybe you can remove next line):
                Thread.sleep(3000);

                for (Handler handler : server.getHandlers()) {
                    handler.stop();
                }
                server.stop();
                server.getThreadPool().join();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Failed to stop Jetty");
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my service don't have any interaction UI. Furthermore, what is the type of "server" variable? Does server.stop invoke ServletContextListener.onContextDestroyed() event?

Comment: Server is of type: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server. Yes, that event is invoked, but I dont know if its server.stop() or handler.stop().